# ajax prompt as user types a location

Tags: google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a search engine and as the user types a location I want to prompt them, just like Google Map does. I see www.skillpages.com does. It seems to use google api to prompt the location. But a site like monster.com, which also prompts the location, does not appear to use google api and seems to a have its own database of towns and cities (I came to this conclusion after looking through the source code and testing a few locations).

Which is the best way to do this? Is there an issue with excessive usage if using google map api to prompt for a location?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about excessive usage of the API, you could always cache the results so if you're getting a lot of queries you would just need to pull them out of the cache.

Another tip: Only prompt after a certain amount of letters. If you start calling the API after you've typed one letter, you'll be making a tonne of calls and ultimately its not needed. I would never be able to find any location I want with a single letter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Are there advantages to using our own database of locations and long/lats? Or is it best to utilize google map api?

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel if I'm honest. If there's an API there to use, it's pointless going through and spending a lot of time creating this database.